# Remote Debugging Blazor WASM on Azure?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-webassembly, azure-appservice

I've tried using the standard Blazor template app to remote debug on an Azure app service and I get the following error:(the app run fine if a compile to release, though not debugging of course.)
[image]

I compile to debug any CPU.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I can debugger in my `.razor` pages.

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

Judging from your error message, the problem may be caused by unsuccessful release of some files and other factors when the program was released.

In order to solve your problem, you can tell us the version of Visual Studio you are using and how you created the project. This problem is mostly related to your development tool environment configuration.

**Here is a suggestion**, test it by yourself and it runs normally.

1. Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise Edition (other versions should also be normal)
2. Configuration before project release

[image]

3. Start remote debugging

[image]

[image]

4. The final result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.1
I got it to work with the standard template project, but still getting the errors on my much larger project.  Also, the debugger would only allow breakpoints in the controller, not the pages (symbol not attached).  Are you able to have breakpoints on pages when remote debug?

Comment: @Mike Yes, I can debug in my razor pages. My VS Version is `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.7.1`.